# Angularjs routes seems to be not loading in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl, angularjs-rails

I'm trying to build my first app with Rails 4 and Angularjs, I have some experience in Rails and totally new to Angular, and I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails).

I use `rabl` to generate the json from my controller and it looks like

`[{"recipe":{"id":1,"name":"Pizza","servings":1,"steps":[{"step":{"id":1,"name":"step 1"}}]}},{"recipe":{"id":2,"name":"Pasta","servings":1,"steps":[{"step":{"id":2,"name":"step 2"}}]}}]`

My controller

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller.r
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end
end
```

route `root 'recipes#index'`

Layout

```
!!!
%html{'ng-app' => 'recipe'}
  %head
    %title WILT
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js'
    = javascript_include_tag '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    %div{ 'ng-view' => '' }
      = yield
```

and following is my Angular route

```
#app/assets/javascripts/main.js
this.recipe = angular.module('recipe',["ngRoute"]);

this.recipe.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  return $routeProvider.otherwise({
     templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
     controller: 'RecipeCtrl'
  });
}]);
```

and my Angular controller

```
#app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/RecipeCtrl.js
this.recipe.controller('RecipeCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

and I also have a template in `public/templates/home.html`

Problem is , when I navigate to root `http://localhost:3000`, it gives me the JSON output via `rabl` instead of loading the `angular` template.

I checked the `app/assets/javascripts/main.js` with a break point and it not loading at all. I have already removed the `turbolinks`. What am I missing?

My application.js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree .
```

I'm using

- rails4
- haml-rails
- angularjs-rails
- rabl
- oj

### Update

- start using Angular from CDN
- added 'ngRoute' to module

but still the same, renders the rabl JSON instead of Angular template

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my issue ( Agian... ), the issue was, I need to load the `main.js` file explicitly, and I need to have page to render inside `app/views/recipes`

I so did the following steps

- created a view file `#app/views/recipes/index.html.haml`
- rename the `main.js` to `recipes.js`

Comment: Seems like JS file named like the controller is a thing for `angularjs-rails`... Have a similar problem, trying to investigate the root cause.